# dplyr select function gives error in a for loop

Tags: dplyr

I want to select columns to do something, but it gives me an error.

```
mydata <- read.table(text =  "A B  C  X1 X2
1 0 1 11 15
1 0 1 12 16
0 1 1 13 17
1 1 0 14 18
", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE ) 
mydata

for (i in c("A", "C")){
    df <- mydata %>% select(i)
    #and then use df to downstream work
}
```

error log:

```
Error in select(., i): <text>:1:7: unexpected symbol
1: Using an
          ^
Traceback:

1. mydata %>% select(i) %>% head
2. head(.)
3. select(., i)
4. select.data.frame(., i)
5. tidyselect_fix_call(tidyselect::eval_select(expr(c(...)), .data), 
 .     call = error_call)
```

I am sorry to bother you, but after my search, I still cannot find a solution. How to solve this? thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use `mydata %>% select(A, C)`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your quick reply! I want to select one variable at a time, The "i" should be in `select()`?

Comment: What do you want to do in the end? print the first rows (i.e. `head`?)

Comment: I am sorry, I updated my question...

Comment: But it does work: check `for (i in c("A", "C")){
  df <- mydata %>% 
    select(i)
}`

Comment: I don't know why I still get errors with the code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`dplyr` uses tidy evaluation, so you have to do some quote/unquote of the `i` variable.

```
for (i in c("A", "C")){
    df <- mydata %>% select({{i}})
    #and then use df to downstream work
}
```

You can read more [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/)

---

Edit: that being said, using select in a for-loop isn't very tidy-esque, and you would probably be better of using `dplyr` in a more standard fashion.

Comment: Thank you, I will be appreciated it if you could kindly give the `dplyr` standard fashion example. ^_^.

Comment: Difficult to do without knowing your downstream analysis.

Comment: For example, I just want to know how to  use `dplyr` without for-loop: `for (i in c("A", "C")){
    df <- mydata %>% 
        select({{i}}) %>%
        count
}`